# NodeJs : maintain a script running for a given time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I have quickly and poorly written a Node.Js script without any kind of error handling which does the job and eventually crashes once in a while upon encountering an error. Careless but efficient.

To keep it running, I can use npm forever and have it restart forever. Fancy.

Now let's say I want it to run for 12 hours (with some module / code to restart it after a crash) and then stop completely.

Any simple way of achieving such a behavior ?

Comment: "Careless but efficient". This is the problem. I read it as Fast but Useless.

Comment: ;-) @Vohuman : I beg to disagree. The script is an amateur bot for personal use only. When it crashes, it only hinders me, and not much. A crash doesn't affect its efficiency at all if it's restarted immediately by foreverJs. I am still developing it, and learning how to properly use Node in the process, the rare error handling being left for the end. Besides, you can remove the introduction (meant to laugh only), the question still stands :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your node.js process to stop itself after 12 hours, you can just set a timer for 12 hours from now and call `process.exit()`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    process.exit(0);
}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12);
```

---

If you want to use a system like forever, but you both want to stop the program in 12 hours and don't want forever to restart it, then you can just run a **chron job**, scheduled for 12 hours from now to execute **`forever stop /somepath/yourscript.js`**.

---

P.S. There's no way that a system that crashes on its own every so often is "careless, but efficient".  It may be quick to get going, but it's also loose and dangerous and is never the efficient way to code in the long run.  I'd suggest you start removing all the [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) you've baked into your code.

My favorite saying from running development teams for many years was the somewhat rhetorical question: "Why is there never enough time to do it right the first time, but always enough time to do it over to get it right."

Comment: Complete answer with different solutions and advice against carelessness. Thanks. Though if I add : "I'm an amateur learning Node who recently understood how asynchronous programming works, I keep improving previous code while building my project, and my main problem in life is that I never do anything because I want everything I do to be perfect", will you keep lecturing me for what I said ? ;-) This post is some kind of therapy for me ! Cheers !

Comment: @KLôN - Well, while you're at it, you can read about [Minimum Viable Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product), but nowhere in there does it say your code should be poorly designed and full of bugs.  If you're just learning obviously you have to learn as you go, but a very important part of learning is learning how to write robust, stable code that handles error conditions.  You shouldn't think that an auto-restart is a substitute for learning how to keep the code from crashing.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. To be completely honest, I have already started handling errors when absolutely required, and I'm planning to use what I've learned to cover all possibles outcomes. Thx for your time and advice !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Linux "at" command to set a relative timer. Forever will handle restarting your script if it crashes.

1. Start your script

   `forever start /path/yourscript.js`
2. Schedule the stop command

   `echo 'forever stop /path/yourscript.js' | at now + 12 hours`

--

Note you may need to install "at" - ex. (`apt-get install at`)

Note you can also schedule "at" to execute a shell script:

- Create a file "stopscript.sh" containing this line: `forever stop /path/yourscript.js`
- Set an "at" job: `at now +12 hours -f ~/stopscript.sh`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a UNIXy operating system, you can use the `at` command to kill forever at a given time.

Example:

```
$ echo 'forever stop whatever.js' | at now + 12 hours
```

Answer (score 1):

use `cluster` module, master restart the cluster when there is an error.

in master, simply run code like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    process.exit(0);
}, 12 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: Your math is a bit off for how to do a `setTimeout()` for 12 hours from now.  You are off by a factor of 1000.